# Flutter: Correct way to debug widget rebuilds

Tags: flutter

How can I see what is causing my widgets to keep propagating the widget tree? I'm using the Provider package and experiencing a problem where the widgets keep stacking up - for example, if I add a print statement to the homepage:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("Home");
```

Then after navigating around the app for a while, if I clear the debug console and load the homepage or any screens below it, I will get multiple "Home" printouts, ie:

```
flutter: Home
flutter: Home
flutter: Home
flutter: Home
flutter: Home
flutter: Home
```

The more I navigate around the app, the more they stack up. What would be the correct way to debug this?

Comment: Not directly related, but it's likely because you have more than one Home route in your navigation history

Comment: Thank you!!!!! Based on that comment, I found out that a custom HomeButton widget (on Custom AppBar) with `Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/')` was the culprit! Replaced it with `Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName('/'))` and it's working :) I was looking everywhere else but there to try figure it out!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use Flutter's devtools https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/devtools/overview

It possesses a few helpful screens such as: [image]

This screen includes a detailed tree of the widgets that rebuilt within the given time frame.

Answer (score 4):

The ["Flutter Performance" tool](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/android-studio#show-performance-data) displays widget rebuilds in real-time as you interact with the app, in Debug mode.

[image]

---

From its [documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/android-studio#show-performance-data) (same URL as above):

> The exact count of the rebuilds for this frame displays in the second
>   column from the right. For a high number of rebuilds, a yellow
>   spinning circle displays. The column to the far right shows how many
>   times a widget was rebuilt since entering the current screen. For
>   widgets that aren’t rebuilt, a solid grey circle displays. Otherwise,
>   a grey spinning circle displays.

The linked page includes further profiling tips, notably:

> Note that numerous rebuilds doesn’t necessarily indicate a problem. Typically you should only worry about excessive rebuilds if you have already run the app in profile mode and verified that the performance is not what you want.

---

Personally and on a more educational level, watching the rebuild behavior in real-time while interacting with UI has helped me grasp specific Flutter widgets and mechanisms.

**As of December 2019 this tool is only available on the Flutter plugins for Android Studio and IntelliJ.**

Answer (score 3):

Try the `BuildTracker` from https://pub.dev/packages/debug_tools

It allows to track stack traces that lead to widgets being marked dirty and hence causing rebuilds.

Example run:

### Widgets that were built

- `ValueListenableBuilder<String> ← [root]`
- `Directionality ← ValueListenableBuilder<String> ← [root]`
- `Text ← Directionality ← ValueListenableBuilder<String> ← [root]`

### Widgets that were marked dirty (build roots)

#### ValueListenableBuilder ← [root]:

```
  State.setState                           package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 1287:15
  _ValueListenableBuilderState._valueChanged package:flutter/src/widgets/value_listenable_builder.dart 182:5
  ChangeNotifier.notifyListeners           package:flutter/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart 243:25
  ValueNotifier.value=                     package:flutter/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart 309:5
* main.<fn>                                test/build_tracker_test.dart 25:10
...
```